How can I make bento 2 occupy all the remaining width of bento 1?
im trying to do a bento, but i need to put the bento 2 almost in the middle of the 4 bento, but i dont know how to do it, if i set width 70% in the 1 bento, the bento 2 remains the same
html and css
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="bento-wrapper">
        <div class="bento bento-1">1</div>
        <div class="bento bento-2">2</div>
        <div class="bento bento-3">3</div>
        <div class="bento bento-4">4</div>
        <div class="bento bento-5">5</div>
        <div class="bento bento-6">6</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  border: 1px solid white;
  width: 60vw;
  height: 80vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.bento-wrapper {
  border: 1px solid white;
  width: 90%;
  height: 85%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 2%;
}

.bento {
  border: 1px solid pink;
  border-radius: 20px;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.bento-1 {
  width: 70%;
}

.bento-2 {
}

.bento-3 {
  grid-row: span 3;
}

.bento-6 {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

i tried to use span 2, span 3, grid columns and row, using % but i it doesnt work
here is the code pen link
https://codepen.io/karensitauwu/pen/mybVyqE
here is the example image, i just enter image description here

I think it would be helpful if you could give an image if what you are trying to achieve. For example I can’t work out what “in the middle of 4 bento” means.

i added an image @AHaworth

One way is to take out a ruler and measure the relative widths of the various elements.
You will find that the ratios of the first three are 2: 3: 4.
Also note that the first and fifth elements are square (aspect-ratio 1) and the 6th element has an aspect ratio of 5:2.
This snippet therefore sets up a grid with 5 * 1fr, 4fr and makes bento-1 etc start on the correct column and with the correct span (number of columns).


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="bento-wrapper">
      <div class="bento bento-1">1</div>
      <div class="bento bento-2">2</div>
      <div class="bento bento-3">3</div>
      <div class="bento bento-4">4</div>
      <div class="bento bento-5">5</div>
      <div class="bento bento-6">6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>

<style>
  * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  body {
    background-color: black;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
  }
  
  .container {
    width: 100vmin;
    height: fit-content;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  .bento-wrapper {
    width: 90%;
    height: fit-content;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr) 4fr;
    gap: 2%;
  }
  
  .bento {
    border: 1px solid pink;
    border-radius: 20px;
    color: white;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  
  .bento-1 {
    grid-column: span 2;
    aspect-ratio: 1;
  }
  
  .bento-2 {
    grid-column: 3 / span 3;
  }
  
  .bento-3 {
    grid-column: 6 / span 4;
    grid-row: span 3;
  }
  
  .bento-4 {
    grid-column: span 3;
  }
  
  .bento-5 {
    grid-column: span 2;
    aspect-ratio: 1;
  }
  
  .bento-6 {
    grid-column: span 5;
    aspect-ratio: 5 / 2;
  }
</style>



